# Form post Send data to another page , verify and then post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with , [image: Form Page]

In the form after user clicks on Submit , he will be taken to another page which would show all the data entered, Which would allow the user to verify the content.(User will have a look at the content , to see what he entered is correct).

Once user verifies he would submit the data and Insert to DB should be done.

I want to know a method in which i could carry on the approach, to do this.

How can i implement this

EDIT MORE EXPLAIN

addemp.php

The Main Div With Form

```
<div class="panel-body">
<form>
Employee : <input Type="text" id="name">
<input type="submit" value="check">
</div>
```

The Second Div in the same form should show once submit is clicked

```
<div class="submit panel-body">
<form>
Employee : <Employee Name asin main div>
<input type="submit" > <--! this submit would post data
</form>
</div>
```

how to pass the value from 1st div to the second , and from the second INSERT to db.how can i do without page refresh ?

Comment: I am Using PHP For Inserting Data , let me know approaches on doing this

Comment: i want to know about some methods, how can i do this .

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You don't need to use a form in this case. You can simply use JQuery to show the data from text boxes in a DIV and a button that will POST the data for you on the server.

```
    <input type="text" name="nric"  id="nric" />
    <input type="text" name="empName" id="empName" />
    <input type="text" name="location" id="location" />
    <input id="sndData" type="button" value="Submit" />

<div id="showData"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#sndData').click(function(){
    var makeData = "<p>NRIC: "+$('#nric').val()+"</p><p>Employee Name: "+$('#empName').val()+"</p><p>Location: "+$('#location').val()+"</p>";
    $('#showData').html(makeData);
});
```

When you've done that, just create/show a HTML button that will POST the data for you.
If this answers your question, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Hey thanks , for that you created a work flow for me. I want to keep the section of the form and showing the data in the same page.User sees the data rechecks and clicks on submit\

Comment: Edited the code according to your specifications. Now the `<form>` tag will submit the page on itself using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and when the page would load again, it will check whether `$_POST` is empty or not. If it is not empty (meaning the data has been posted, it will echo it for you. 
Be advised that it is just basic code. You'd have to put up basic checks like multiple white spaces etc.
Please accept it as an answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: yes , but without page refresh how can i carry on ? Do check the Question Updated

Comment: Do you mean you have to perform the whole validation action without a page refresh?

Comment: I dont need any validation , just the data from the input field show up in label in the next div.

Answer (score 0):

Use following script on location file

```
$action='';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//create form here
//Change the action of form
$action = 'save.php';
}
echo '<form method="POST" action="'.$action.'">
<input type="text" name="nric" value="'.isset($_POST['nric'])?$_POST['nric'].'" />
<input type="text" name="empName" value="'.isset($_POST['empName'])?$_POST['empName'].'" />
<input type="text" name="location" value="'.isset($_POST['location'])?$_POST['location'].'" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>';
```

Comment: Without post , and page refresh how can i ?

Comment: If you don't want to refresh page then you have to use ajax for it

Comment: $('form').on('submit',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $formpostdata = $(this).serialize() // make ajax call here with data });

Comment: Yes how to send the data from the first , div to the next , without page refresh.

Comment: Similar to when we fill up college admission form we first fill up all the data , when we click on next we are show with all the data we entered so we can verify what we have entered and finally post when done \